# How can i create a mapping properly?

Tags: mapping, struct

I would like to create a mapping with a struct inside as key

```
struct MyMap { 
   bytes32 data1; 
   address data2; 
   string  data3;
} 
mapping(MyMap => bool) public currentMap;
```

but i am getting this error:

Only elementary types, user defined value types, contract types or enums are allowed as mapping keys.

Answer (score 1):

Structs cannot be used as key in mappings

from the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/types.html#mapping-types):

mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType)

> The _KeyType can be any built-in value type, bytes, string, or any contract or enum type. Other user-defined or complex types, such as mappings, structs or array types are not allowed